# Remove string after character in every line break

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm a newbie at javascript and I have some text that contains multiple lines.I want to remove strings after the character '(' in every line breaks and then replace all line breaks with commas. This is what I have so far

```
var text = "black gloves (?) 36622\nred eyes (?) 587624\nsolo (?) 1975043\nshort hair (?) 1628547"

var draft = text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,",");
var final = draft.split('(')[0];
alert(final);
```

I can't seem to get my code to give me this result:

```
black gloves,red eyes,solo,short hair
```

but instead it just gives `black gloves`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var text = "black gloves (?) 36622\nred eyes (?) 587624\nsolo (?) 1975043\nshort hair (?) 1628547"

var draft = text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ");
var draft = draft.replace(/(\d)+/gm,",");
var draft = draft.replace(/\(\?\)/gm,"");
alert(draft);
```

OR

```js
var text = "black gloves (?) 36622\nred eyes (?) 587624\nsolo (?) 1975043\nshort hair (?) 1628547"

var draft = text.replace(/\(\?\)[ \d\r\n]+/gm,",");
alert(draft);
```

Answer (score 1):

You must know that [**String.prototype.split()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) returns an `array` and in this case it's not necessary to use it.

You just need to use [**String.prototype.replace()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to achieve what you want, as follows:

```js
var text = "black gloves (?) 36622\nred eyes (?) 587624\nsolo (?) 1975043\nshort hair (?) 1628547";

var draft = text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, ",").replace(/[^a-zA-Z,]/g, " ").replace(/\s+,/g, ",").trim();
console.log(draft);
```

Comment: How can i get rid of the numbers as well?

Comment: the updated code seems to remove spaces which I don't want

Comment: @TravelWhere, oh sry, I forgot it.

Answer (score 1):

Here it goeshttps://jsfiddle.net/loginshivam/724phqag/

```
var text = "black gloves (?) 36622\nred eyes (?) 587624\nsolo (?) 1975043\nshort hair (?) 1628547"

var array = text.split("\n");
var val;
for(in=0;in<array.length;in++){
    val=array[in];
    if(in == 0)
       text = val.substring(0, val.indexOf("(")) ;
    else
    text = text  + ","+ val.substring(0, val.indexOf("("));
}
```

Comment: Might want to put `var` before `index=0`, or you'll be making/updating `window.index`.

Answer (score 1):

Without the regex:

```js
var text = "black gloves (?) 36622\nred eyes (?) 587624\nsolo (?) 1975043\nshort hair (?) 1628547"

var textToArray = text.split('\n');
for(var i = 0; i<textToArray.length; i++) {
    var index = textToArray[i].indexOf('(') - 1;
    textToArray[i] = textToArray[i].slice(0,index);
}
var finalString = textToArray.join(', ');
alert(finalString);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
text.replace(/ \(.\) \d+/g, '').replace(/\r?\n/g, ',')
```

Just as simple as one line two replaces.

```js
var text = "black gloves (?) 36622\nred eyes (?) 587624\nsolo (?) 1975043\nshort hair (?) 1628547";

var final = text.replace(/ \(.\) \d+/g, '').replace(/\r?\n/g, ',');

alert(final);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate regex solution (https://regex101.com/ is very helpful). It's a bit brittle in that it assumes each line is properly formatted and contains the pattern.

```js
var text = "black gloves (?) 36622\nred eyes (?) 587624\nsolo (?) 1975043\nshort hair (?) 1628547"

console.log(text.replace(/ \(\?\) .*(\n|$)/g, ",").slice(0,-1));
```